# Programming the Pepper robot without "Choreography" software?

Tags: pepper

Usually the developer can use Softbanks own software **Choreography** to give programs to Pepper robot.

Isn't there a way to setup a different development environment? e.g. Access via SSH and creating Python scripts with a simple text editor and starting the script manually? It means writing and starting Python scripts for Pepper without using **Choreography**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, using Choregraphe is not an obligation, you can use the different [SDKs](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/dev/programming_index.html) directly.
You can for instance create a python script on your computer, copy it on the robot

```
scp path/to/script/myscript.py nao@robotIp
```

And then ssh onto the robot and launch the script

```
ssh nao@robotIp
python myscript.py
```

You can also ssh onto the robot, create a script (using nano for instance) and launch it from there.

Comment: Great! Just to prevent such simple questions in the future. Where exactly is this "interface" documented? I wasn't aware of an ssh shell? What system is behind it? Can I install new packages? e.g. `apt-get install vim` ? ;)

Comment: You can also copy them to the robot using winscp or ftp, then launch them directly using the ALLauncher module: http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-1/naoqi/core/allauncher.html. Or from a short choregraphe behavior...

Comment: I still can ot find in the documentation the topic about SSH or other "direct" access possibilities. Can you help me here. And what OS does Pepper use?

Comment: Here http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/dev/tools/opennao.html?highlight=ssh
and here: http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/dev/libqi/guide/qicli.html?highlight=ssh

Answer (score 3):

You can also use qibuild (pip install qibuild) : https://github.com/aldebaran/qibuild

It contains a qipkg command, just run

qipkg deploy-package path/to/your/file.pml --url USER@IP:/home/nao

A pml file is a project, it is created by Choregraph, or you can use this tool : 
https://github.com/pepperhacking/robot-jumpstarter

in order to get a sample app.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using Pycharm Pro for 6 months and I am happy with it. You get automatic deployment and remote debugging. The most basic setup must still be done with Choregraphe, but it takes less than one minut.